# Как сделать так, чтобы activity при нажатии кнопки назад никак не изменялось

Tags: java, android, activity

Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии кнопки назад на экране телефона ничего не происходило.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто переопределите метод `onBackPressed` в активити так, чтобы он ничего не делал:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     //ничего не делаем
}
```